# Linear algebra: function and vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

I'm having problems with these two exercises:

1 - Functions: $f(t) = t^3 - 1$, $g(t) = t^2 + t - 1$ and $h(t) = t + 2$.

Is there any $k、\in\mathbb R$  that satisfy this condition: $f(t) + k \cdot g(t) = h(t)$?

2 - The set $V = \{(x, y)\mid x,y\in\mathbb R\}$ has the following operation:

$$a(x,y) = (x, ay)$$

Knowing that $V$ is not a vector space, which one of the axioms is not verified?

The first question I know it doesn't exist, but I don't know how to get there. The second question i've tried all $4$ axioms(multiplication) and to me, all of them were verified. Could any of you help me please? Thank you very much

Comment: @For the second question I have added my answer to my post.

Comment: Where? I can't find it

Comment: Refresh the page. you'll find it added to my original answer.

Comment: I refreshed three times, but it appeared now. I'll read it. English is not my native language, so i'm having a few problems to understand the "hold for all Ts" you keep saying, but thanks anyway

Comment: You're most welcome. Nor is English mine :) So I'm sorry here that I may have misused some words that cause trouble for your understanding. **hold for all ts** means that whatever you let $t$ be, the "$=$" will never ever be violated.

Comment: Oh, and to the = keep "unviolated" i need to have the T's raised to the same power? So, if the = is violated, K doesn't exist? is that it?

Comment: Exactly. Counterparts must be **totally the same** (the coefficients and the powers). For instance, $t$ and $t^{2}$, or $(k+1)t$ and $(k-1)t$, both can never become "conterparts". (by the way the word "counterpart" may not be an accurate mathematical description here but sorry that I cannot think up a better one for now. I'm always short of vocabulary (╯$\nabla$╰))

Comment: So the signals(+ or -) and powers need always to be the same? if i had k = -k they are not counterparts? No problem, i can understand it

Comment: Not the signals. I mean the coefficients must be the same. If you have $kt^i=-kt^i$ and you need them to be counterparts you just need to let $k=-k$ and that's $k=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by coefficients then?

Comment: For example in this polynomial $$2t^2+t-1$$, $2$ is the coefficient for $t^2$, $1$ for $t^1$ and $-1$ for $t^0$.

Comment: Oh, that's what i thought. Thank you very much for all these explanations and for your time. Really, thank you!

Comment: Je t'en prie. Just feel free to ask questions on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question: $f(t) + k\cdot g(t) = h(t)$ just amounts to $t^3-1+k(t^2+t-1)=t+2$, i.e. $t^3+kt^2+kt-1-k=t+2$. LHS has a $t^3$ which has no counterpart in RHS, thus the equation can't always hold for all $t$s.
For the second, in fact there are **eight** , not just four axioms that are required for a vector space. Here I'm afraid this axiom:
$$1\cdot \vec v=\vec v , \forall \vec v \in V$$
is violated.
Just check this:
$$2(1,1)=(1+1)\cdot(1,1)\overset{distributivity}{=}1\cdot (1,1)+1\cdot (1,1)=(1,1)+(1,1)=(2,2)$$
But under your scalar multiplication rule
$$2(1,1)=(1,2)$$
The two results  therefore contradict.

Comment: I know tha there are eight, 4 related to addition, 4 related to multiplication. The addition rule I already tested the four of them and they are true. That's why I just sent the multiplication rule. But anyway, I can't find which of the axioms are not verified using this rule

Comment: So can you please show me what the addition rule is? Perhaps it also plays a role in this problem.

Comment: All right. The addition rule is: (x1, y1) + (x2, y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)

Comment: About the first one, in the LHS i have 3 results for that equation and in the RHS i have just 1. That's why it does not exist?

Comment: Not for this. actually, if a polynomial equation always holds whatever value is given to the parameter (just as in this case), then every $t^i$ in LHS must have a counterpart in RHS in order that they can always cancel, Otherwise the equation could not always hold.

Comment: Ok, what about the second question?

Comment: So, to exist any K I would need to have for example:

kt³ + kt + t = t³ + t ?

Comment: In this case $kt^3+(k+1)t=t^3+t$. If you are to make this equation always hold, then $kt^3$ must always cancel $t^3$ and $(k+1)t$ must cancel $t$, which will yield, respectively ,$k=1$ and $k=0$. So it is not possible, neither.

Comment: About the second one: Why do i need to change 2.(1, 1) to (1+1).(1,1) ?Thank you very much

Comment: All right, so i would need to have kt³ + t = t³ + t to cancel everything, is that it?

Comment: Why not?  By doing so we have proved $V$ is not linear, exactly what we want isn't it(⊙o⊙)?